# Install gcc in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, gcc, llvm, osx-mountain-lion, rbenv

I need GCC for some Ruby gems. And I need LLVM as well for iOS development using Xcode 4.4. I already have LLVM installed through Xcode.

How can I install GCC in Mountain Lion without affecting any of LLVM binaries?

Comment: Can you just download, compile, and install gcc from source?

Comment: Xcode installs gcc 4.2 as well as the llvm compiler, so you should already have it. If you need a different version though then I suggest [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had Homebrew. So I did this.

```
brew install --enable-all-languages https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/master/gcc.rb
```

It worked!

Answer (score 6):

The fact is that because you have Xcode you **already** have GCC installed on your system. If you're trying to run GCC from the terminal and getting "command not found" then the reason is, starting with OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion), the GCC "command line tools" are not installed by default with Xcode.  The install procedure depends on your version of OS X and Xcode:

Installing the GCC command line tools in OS X 10.8 (Xcode 4.4):
Xcode -> Preferences -> Download -> Components -> Command Line Tools -> install

Installing the GCC command line tools in OS X 10.9 (Xcode 5.02):
I have not tried these instructions myself, but I'll move them here if someone tries them and they work:
http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/

Comment: No such component, at least anymore (5.0.2)

Comment: @PawelVeselov Yes, it seems this has changed with Mavericks. The issue is still missing command-line tools, though, just the install procedure has changed. Could you check the updated install procedure and let me know if it works for you?

Comment: I can't confirm ATM, since I already have XCode installed, I apparently had the tools (in that sense that link is correct). However, they are no longer buried deep in XCode directories, and are available from /usr, but there are a lot of scripts and how-tos out there that assume they are. And XCode doesn't have them as a separate component anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue after upgrading to Mountain Lion.

My fix, I found make and gcc etc in `/Developer/usr/bin`.

```
setenv PATH $PATH":/Developer/usr/bin"
```

Puts them back in the path.

Oh yeah, I was on Xcode 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

Install [macports](http://macports.org) and run:

```
$ sudo port install gcc
```

from the command line.  There are about [20 different versions of gcc available as Macports](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=gcc).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install anything on a Mac is by using [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/). There is a package for this very purpose:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install apple-gcc42
```